# Nginx - Is it possible to know which server is chosen?

Tags: nginx

In Nginx,
Is it possible to get which server is chosen (for each request) when using load balance?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add new logging format,

```
$ log_format upstreamlog '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name  to: $upstream_addr: $request upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time msec $msec request_time $request_time';
```

and then redefine `access_log` as

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstreamlog;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!